# Talend Installation of Custom Components from Github

Tags: github, talend

since Talend has deprecated the exchange functionality, custom components have to be installed via Github. However, i followed the instructions from Talend [here](https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/8.0/install-update-custom-compt/installing-custom-component) which is simple enough using the following component: https://github.com/jlolling/talendcomp_tGoogleAnalytics4Management

According to the Talend instruction, i should alter the xml file in src/main/components
/tGoogleAnalytics4Management/, which i did, and then copy the folder src/main/components
/tGoogleAnalytics4Management/ where i have other components, which i did. Next, i should go into Talend [image: here] and reference the respective folder. However, the component never shows up.

Answer (score 1):

This is very well explained in the official documentation:
https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/8.0/studio-user-guide/how-to-define-user-component-folder-talend-components

TLDR: Create a folder such as
`C:/Talend/CustomComponents/`
Unzip the component here, i.e: `C:/Talend/CustomComponents/myComp/myComp_java.xml`
specify only the customComponents and studio will scan all the components from that folder